# How to change the format for the searched data in a date filter in Angular

Tags: angularjs, date, filter

I have a table that I filter with `ngRepeat`. One of the columns is a date, I like showing date in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`, so all the date column look that way but when I enter the date in the filter input it doesn't know that it should search it in a different format, so it can't find the date looked for.

I've tried nesting filters without success, does anyone know how to do it?

Here is my code:

```
<input ng-model="filFecha"  />

<tr ng-repeat="pedido in pedidos | 
    filter:{codigo:filCodigo,
    tercero:filTercero, 
    fechaCreacion: ($filter('date')(filFecha, 'dd/MM/yyyy')), 
    estado:filEstado} | 
    orderBy: orderProp">

    <td class="corta">{{pedido.fechaCreacion | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td class="corta">{{pedido.estado}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here's a Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3942/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built a custom filter that I think solves your problem.

```
myApp.filter('dateFilter', function(){
    return function(arr, field){
        var filtered = [];        
        angular.forEach(arr, function(item){            
            if(moment(item.fechaCreacion).format('DD/MM/YYYY').indexOf(field) > -1)
                filtered.push(item);
        });
        return filtered;
    }
});
```

It loops through each item in `$scope.pedidos` and uses moment.js to convert fechaCreacion to a string in your desired format (DD/MM/YYYY).  It then checks if the value of filFecha exists in that string anywhere and if it does, it adds it to the filtered array.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="pedido in pedidos | 
    filter:{codigo:filCodigo, tercero:filTercero,
    estado:filEstado} | 
    dateFilter: filFecha |
    orderBy: orderProp">
```

Have a look at the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/9xgEP/).

Answer (score 0):

try momentjs their library makes formatting dates very simple and easy. so when you get an incoming date just use this line of code:

```
var formattedDate = moment(inputDate, ['YYYYMMdd', 'MM-dd-YYYY', 'dd-MM-YYYY').format('MM/dd/YYYY');
```

this will take the input date and try to match it to one of the formats in the array of strings and if it recognizes one it will then format it to the string passed in to the `format` function.

if $scope.pedido.fechaCreacion is the date you are trying to format then try this:

```
{{moment(pedido.fechaCreacion, [expectedFormats]).format('MM/dd/YYYY')}}
```

Comment: Hmmm doesn't work on the ng-repeat statement, and I can do a good formating using angular filters without momentjs, {{pedido.fechaCreacion | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} this works great, the problem is with filFecha, if I enter 29/05/2014 it doesn't get filtered but 2014-05-29 does work

Comment: try {{moment(pedido.fechaCreacion, 'dd/MM/YYYY').format('MM/dd/YYYY')}} maybe then?

Answer (score 0):

I liked the custom filter but wanted to extend it to be more flexible. I also did not want to use moment as that is not what I was using to format my date on the UI.

Checkout the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/CraigSelbert/1579606d1c746af93a07)

Checkout the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0tnpeg4d/)

```
angular.module('dateFilter', []).filter('dateFilter', function ($filter) {
    return function (array, config) {

        if (config === undefined || config.field === undefined || config.format === undefined || config.property === undefined)
            return array;

        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(array, function (item) {
            if ($filter('date')(new Date(getPropByString(item, config.property)), config.format).indexOf(config.field) > -1)
                filtered.push(item);
        });

        return filtered;
    }
```